# Customize cordova Splash Screen for android platform

Tags: android, cordova, npm, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I want to customize splash screen of my cordova project.
Here is my inserted code in config.xml file to change splash screen

```
<preference name = "SplashScreen" value = "screen" />
<preference name = "SplashScreenDelay" value = "3000" />
<preference name = "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value = "true" />
<splash src="/HelloworldProject/splashimages/splash.png"platform="android"  width="720" height="1280" />
```

I can't see any changes when i run my app.Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Try these suggestions out:

1. Looks like there should be a space before `platform`.
2. The `SplashScreen` preference should have the value of that src file; not `screen`

Try this out specifically (modelled after [cordova apache docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#browser-quirks)):

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="/HelloworldProject/splashimages/splash.png" /> <!-- defaults to "/img/logo.png" -->
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" /> <!-- defaults to "3000" -->
<preference name = "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value = "true" />
<splash src="/HelloworldProject/splashimages/splash.png" width="720" height="1280" />
```

If you want, you could put the `splash` tag within a `platform` tag with `name="android"`:

```
<platform name="android">
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="/HelloworldProject/splashimages/splash.png" />
</platform>
```